# Validation Auto-Renewable Subscriptions

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I've read all the documentation there is and basically every post here on SO, but I can't wrap my head around the respons I'm getting from Apple compared to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW4).

The field latest_receipt_info should contain the latest receipt, in which I can find information about the currently active/cancelled subscription. But how to I intepret that data when latest_receipt_info is an array with multiple receipts? Which one gives me the information about what's currently active?

Part of the response below (latest_receipt_info only included):

```
{
"latest_receipt_info": [
    {
        quantity: '1',
        product_id: 'com.purchase.test.debug.7.d.sub',
        transaction_id: '1000000114334946',
        original_transaction_id: '1000000114334946',
        purchase_date: '2014-07-1406: 53: 06Etc/GMT',
        purchase_date_ms: '1405320786698',
        purchase_date_pst: '2014-07-1323: 53: 06America/Los_Angeles',
        original_purchase_date: '2014-06-1713: 51: 36Etc/GMT',
        original_purchase_date_ms: '1403013096000',
        original_purchase_date_pst: '2014-06-1706: 51: 36America/Los_Angeles',
        expires_date: '2014-06-1713: 54: 36Etc/GMT',
        expires_date_ms: '1403013276000',
        expires_date_pst: '2014-06-1706: 54: 36America/Los_Angeles',
        web_order_line_item_id: '1000000028302497',
        is_trial_period: 'false'
    },
    {
        quantity: '1',
        product_id: 'com.purchase.test.debug.7.d.sub',
        transaction_id: '1000000114335055',
        original_transaction_id: '1000000114334946',
        purchase_date: '2014-07-1406: 53: 06Etc/GMT',
        purchase_date_ms: '1405320786698',
        purchase_date_pst: '2014-07-1323: 53: 06America/Los_Angeles',
        original_purchase_date: '2014-06-1713: 53: 54Etc/GMT',
        original_purchase_date_ms: '1403013234000',
        original_purchase_date_pst: '2014-06-1706: 53: 54America/Los_Angeles',
        expires_date: '2014-06-1713: 57: 36Etc/GMT',
        expires_date_ms: '1403013456000',
        expires_date_pst: '2014-06-1706: 57: 36America/Los_Angeles',
        web_order_line_item_id: '1000000028302496',
        is_trial_period: 'false'
    },
    {
        quantity: '1',
        product_id: 'com.purchase.test.debug.7.d.sub',
        transaction_id: '1000000114335517',
        original_transaction_id: '1000000114334946',
        purchase_date: '2014-07-1406: 53: 06Etc/GMT',
        purchase_date_ms: '1405320786698',
        purchase_date_pst: '2014-07-1323: 53: 06America/Los_Angeles',
        original_purchase_date: '2014-06-1713: 56: 52Etc/GMT',
        original_purchase_date_ms: '1403013412000',
        original_purchase_date_pst: '2014-06-1706: 56: 52America/Los_Angeles',
        expires_date: '2014-06-1714: 00: 36Etc/GMT',
        expires_date_ms: '1403013636000',
        expires_date_pst: '2014-06-1707: 00: 36America/Los_Angeles',
        web_order_line_item_id: '1000000028302514',
        is_trial_period: 'false'
    },
    {
        quantity: '1',
        product_id: 'com.purchase.test.debug.7.d.sub',
        transaction_id: '1000000114336049',
        original_transaction_id: '1000000114334946',
        purchase_date: '2014-07-1406: 53: 06Etc/GMT',
        purchase_date_ms: '1405320786698',
        purchase_date_pst: '2014-07-1323: 53: 06America/Los_Angeles',
        original_purchase_date: '2014-06-1713: 59: 53Etc/GMT',
        original_purchase_date_ms: '1403013593000',
        original_purchase_date_pst: '2014-06-1706: 59: 53America/Los_Angeles',
        expires_date: '2014-06-1714: 03: 36Etc/GMT',
        expires_date_ms: '1403013816000',
        expires_date_pst: '2014-06-1707: 03: 36America/Los_Angeles',
        web_order_line_item_id: '1000000028302526',
        is_trial_period: 'false'
    },
    {
        quantity: '1',
        product_id: 'com.purchase.test.debug.7.d.sub',
        transaction_id: '1000000114336281',
        original_transaction_id: '1000000114334946',
        purchase_date: '2014-07-1406: 53: 06Etc/GMT',
        purchase_date_ms: '1405320786698',
        purchase_date_pst: '2014-07-1323: 53: 06America/Los_Angeles',
        original_purchase_date: '2014-06-1714: 02: 53Etc/GMT',
        original_purchase_date_ms: '1403013773000',
        original_purchase_date_pst: '2014-06-1707: 02: 53America/Los_Angeles',
        expires_date: '2014-06-1714: 06: 36Etc/GMT',
        expires_date_ms: '1403013996000',
        expires_date_pst: '2014-06-1707: 06: 36America/Los_Angeles',
        web_order_line_item_id: '1000000028302539',
        is_trial_period: 'false'
    },
    {
        quantity: '1',
        product_id: 'com.purchase.test.debug.7.d.sub',
        transaction_id: '1000000114336522',
        original_transaction_id: '1000000114334946',
        purchase_date: '2014-07-1406: 53: 06Etc/GMT',
        purchase_date_ms: '1405320786698',
        purchase_date_pst: '2014-07-1323: 53: 06America/Los_Angeles',
        original_purchase_date: '2014-06-1714: 06: 08Etc/GMT',
        original_purchase_date_ms: '1403013968000',
        original_purchase_date_pst: '2014-06-1707: 06: 08America/Los_Angeles',
        expires_date: '2014-06-1714: 09: 36Etc/GMT',
        expires_date_ms: '1403014176000',
        expires_date_pst: '2014-06-1707: 09: 36America/Los_Angeles',
        web_order_line_item_id: '1000000028302552',
        is_trial_period: 'false'
    },
    {
        quantity: '1',
        product_id: 'com.purchase.test.debug.7.d.sub',
        transaction_id: '1000000114337482',
        original_transaction_id: '1000000114334946',
        purchase_date: '2014-07-1406: 53: 06Etc/GMT',
        purchase_date_ms: '1405320786698',
        purchase_date_pst: '2014-07-1323: 53: 06America/Los_Angeles',
        original_purchase_date: '2014-06-1714: 23: 15Etc/GMT',
        original_purchase_date_ms: '1403014995000',
        original_purchase_date_pst: '2014-06-1707: 23: 15America/Los_Angeles',
        expires_date: '2014-06-1714: 26: 14Etc/GMT',
        expires_date_ms: '1403015174000',
        expires_date_pst: '2014-06-1707: 26: 14America/Los_Angeles',
        web_order_line_item_id: '1000000028302566',
        is_trial_period: 'false'
    },
    {
        quantity: '1',
        product_id: 'com.purchase.test.debug.7.d.sub',
        transaction_id: '1000000114339121',
        original_transaction_id: '1000000114334946',
        purchase_date: '2014-07-1406: 53: 06Etc/GMT',
        purchase_date_ms: '1405320786698',
        purchase_date_pst: '2014-07-1323: 53: 06America/Los_Angeles',
        original_purchase_date: '2014-06-1714: 34: 03Etc/GMT',
        original_purchase_date_ms: '1403015643000',
        original_purchase_date_pst: '2014-06-1707: 34: 03America/Los_Angeles',
        expires_date: '2014-06-1714: 37: 02Etc/GMT',
        expires_date_ms: '1403015822000',
        expires_date_pst: '2014-06-1707: 37: 02America/Los_Angeles',
        web_order_line_item_id: '1000000028302637',
        is_trial_period: 'false'
    },
    {
        quantity: '1',
        product_id: 'com.purchase.test.debug.7.d.sub',
        transaction_id: '1000000114339309',
        original_transaction_id: '1000000114334946',
        purchase_date: '2014-07-1406: 53: 06Etc/GMT',
        purchase_date_ms: '1405320786698',
        purchase_date_pst: '2014-07-1323: 53: 06America/Los_Angeles',
        original_purchase_date: '2014-06-1714: 39: 06Etc/GMT',
        original_purchase_date_ms: '1403015946000',
        original_purchase_date_pst: '2014-06-1707: 39: 06America/Los_Angeles',
        expires_date: '2014-06-1714: 42: 06Etc/GMT',
        expires_date_ms: '1403016126000',
        expires_date_pst: '2014-06-1707: 42: 06America/Los_Angeles',
        web_order_line_item_id: '1000000028302686',
        is_trial_period: 'false'
    },
    {
        quantity: '1',
        product_id: 'com.purchase.test.debug.7.d.sub',
        transaction_id: '1000000114339481',
        original_transaction_id: '1000000114334946',
        purchase_date: '2014-07-1406: 53: 06Etc/GMT',
        purchase_date_ms: '1405320786698',
        purchase_date_pst: '2014-07-1323: 53: 06America/Los_Angeles',
        original_purchase_date: '2014-06-1714: 43: 18Etc/GMT',
        original_purchase_date_ms: '1403016198000',
        original_purchase_date_pst: '2014-06-1707: 43: 18America/Los_Angeles',
        expires_date: '2014-06-1714: 46: 18Etc/GMT',
        expires_date_ms: '1403016378000',
        expires_date_pst: '2014-06-1707: 46: 18America/Los_Angeles',
        web_order_line_item_id: '1000000028302703',
        is_trial_period: 'false'
    },
    {
        quantity: '1',
        product_id: 'com.purchase.test.debug.7.d.sub',
        transaction_id: '1000000114340210',
        original_transaction_id: '1000000114334946',
        purchase_date: '2014-07-1406: 53: 06Etc/GMT',
        purchase_date_ms: '1405320786698',
        purchase_date_pst: '2014-07-1323: 53: 06America/Los_Angeles',
        original_purchase_date: '2014-06-1714: 47: 26Etc/GMT',
        original_purchase_date_ms: '1403016446000',
        original_purchase_date_pst: '2014-06-1707: 47: 26America/Los_Angeles',
        expires_date: '2014-06-1714: 50: 25Etc/GMT',
        expires_date_ms: '1403016625000',
        expires_date_pst: '2014-06-1707: 50: 25America/Los_Angeles',
        web_order_line_item_id: '1000000028302714',
        is_trial_period: 'false'
    },
    {
        quantity: '1',
        product_id: 'com.purchase.test.debug.7.d.sub',
        transaction_id: '1000000114340640',
        original_transaction_id: '1000000114334946',
        purchase_date: '2014-07-1406: 53: 06Etc/GMT',
        purchase_date_ms: '1405320786698',
        purchase_date_pst: '2014-07-1323: 53: 06America/Los_Angeles',
        original_purchase_date: '2014-06-1714: 52: 37Etc/GMT',
        original_purchase_date_ms: '1403016757000',
        original_purchase_date_pst: '2014-06-1707: 52: 37America/Los_Angeles',
        expires_date: '2014-06-1714: 55: 37Etc/GMT',
        expires_date_ms: '1403016937000',
        expires_date_pst: '2014-06-1707: 55: 37America/Los_Angeles',
        web_order_line_item_id: '1000000028302735',
        is_trial_period: 'false'
    },
    {
        quantity: '1',
        product_id: 'com.purchase.test.debug.7.d.sub',
        transaction_id: '1000000114340964',
        original_transaction_id: '1000000114334946',
        purchase_date: '2014-07-1406: 53: 06Etc/GMT',
        purchase_date_ms: '1405320786698',
        purchase_date_pst: '2014-07-1323: 53: 06America/Los_Angeles',
        original_purchase_date: '2014-06-1714: 57: 24Etc/GMT',
        original_purchase_date_ms: '1403017044000',
        original_purchase_date_pst: '2014-06-1707: 57: 24America/Los_Angeles',
        expires_date: '2014-06-1715: 00: 24Etc/GMT',
        expires_date_ms: '1403017224000',
        expires_date_pst: '2014-06-1708: 00: 24America/Los_Angeles',
        web_order_line_item_id: '1000000028302760',
        is_trial_period: 'false'
    },
    {
        quantity: '1',
        product_id: 'com.purchase.test.debug.7.d.sub',
        transaction_id: '1000000114345379',
        original_transaction_id: '1000000114334946',
        purchase_date: '2014-07-1406: 53: 06Etc/GMT',
        purchase_date_ms: '1405320786698',
        purchase_date_pst: '2014-07-1323: 53: 06America/Los_Angeles',
        original_purchase_date: '2014-06-1715: 23: 19Etc/GMT',
        original_purchase_date_ms: '1403018599000',
        original_purchase_date_pst: '2014-06-1708: 23: 19America/Los_Angeles',
        expires_date: '2014-06-1715: 26: 19Etc/GMT',
        expires_date_ms: '1403018779000',
        expires_date_pst: '2014-06-1708: 26: 19America/Los_Angeles',
        web_order_line_item_id: '1000000028302777',
        is_trial_period: 'false'
    },
    {
        quantity: '1',
        product_id: 'com.purchase.test.debug.7.d.sub',
        transaction_id: '1000000114346917',
        original_transaction_id: '1000000114334946',
        purchase_date: '2014-07-1406: 53: 06Etc/GMT',
        purchase_date_ms: '1405320786698',
        purchase_date_pst: '2014-07-1323: 53: 06America/Los_Angeles',
        original_purchase_date: '2014-06-1715: 48: 51Etc/GMT',
        original_purchase_date_ms: '1403020131000',
        original_purchase_date_pst: '2014-06-1708: 48: 51America/Los_Angeles',
        expires_date: '2014-06-1715: 51: 50Etc/GMT',
        expires_date_ms: '1403020310000',
        expires_date_pst: '2014-06-1708: 51: 50America/Los_Angeles',
        web_order_line_item_id: '1000000028302881',
        is_trial_period: 'false'
    },
    {
        quantity: '1',
        product_id: 'com.purchase.test.debug.7.d.sub',
        transaction_id: '1000000116660974',
        original_transaction_id: '1000000114334946',
        purchase_date: '2014-07-1406: 53: 06Etc/GMT',
        purchase_date_ms: '1405320786698',
        purchase_date_pst: '2014-07-1323: 53: 06America/Los_Angeles',
        original_purchase_date: '2014-07-1313: 13: 34Etc/GMT',
        original_purchase_date_ms: '1405257214000',
        original_purchase_date_pst: '2014-07-1306: 13: 34America/Los_Angeles',
        expires_date: '2014-07-1313: 16: 34Etc/GMT',
        expires_date_ms: '1405257394000',
        expires_date_pst: '2014-07-1306: 16: 34America/Los_Angeles',
        web_order_line_item_id: '1000000028302968',
        is_trial_period: 'false'
    },
    {
        quantity: '1',
        product_id: 'com.purchase.test.debug.7.d.sub',
        transaction_id: '1000000116660984',
        original_transaction_id: '1000000114334946',
        purchase_date: '2014-07-1406: 53: 06Etc/GMT',
        purchase_date_ms: '1405320786698',
        purchase_date_pst: '2014-07-1323: 53: 06America/Los_Angeles',
        original_purchase_date: '2014-07-1313: 15: 41Etc/GMT',
        original_purchase_date_ms: '1405257341000',
        original_purchase_date_pst: '2014-07-1306: 15: 41America/Los_Angeles',
        expires_date: '2014-07-1313: 19: 34Etc/GMT',
        expires_date_ms: '1405257574000',
        expires_date_pst: '2014-07-1306: 19: 34America/Los_Angeles',
        web_order_line_item_id: '1000000028393878',
        is_trial_period: 'false'
    },
    {
        quantity: '1',
        product_id: 'com.purchase.test.debug.7.d.sub',
        transaction_id: '1000000116661029',
        original_transaction_id: '1000000114334946',
        purchase_date: '2014-07-1406: 53: 06Etc/GMT',
        purchase_date_ms: '1405320786698',
        purchase_date_pst: '2014-07-1323: 53: 06America/Los_Angeles',
        original_purchase_date: '2014-07-1313: 18: 42Etc/GMT',
        original_purchase_date_ms: '1405257522000',
        original_purchase_date_pst: '2014-07-1306: 18: 42America/Los_Angeles',
        expires_date: '2014-07-1313: 22: 34Etc/GMT',
        expires_date_ms: '1405257754000',
        expires_date_pst: '2014-07-1306: 22: 34America/Los_Angeles',
        web_order_line_item_id: '1000000028393879',
        is_trial_period: 'false'
    },
    {
        quantity: '1',
        product_id: 'com.purchase.test.debug.7.d.sub',
        transaction_id: '1000000116661051',
        original_transaction_id: '1000000114334946',
        purchase_date: '2014-07-1406: 53: 06Etc/GMT',
        purchase_date_ms: '1405320786698',
        purchase_date_pst: '2014-07-1323: 53: 06America/Los_Angeles',
        original_purchase_date: '2014-07-1313: 21: 58Etc/GMT',
        original_purchase_date_ms: '1405257718000',
        original_purchase_date_pst: '2014-07-1306: 21: 58America/Los_Angeles',
        expires_date: '2014-07-1313: 25: 34Etc/GMT',
        expires_date_ms: '1405257934000',
        expires_date_pst: '2014-07-1306: 25: 34America/Los_Angeles',
        web_order_line_item_id: '1000000028393884',
        is_trial_period: 'false'
    },
    {
        quantity: '1',
        product_id: 'com.purchase.test.debug.7.d.sub',
        transaction_id: '1000000116661087',
        original_transaction_id: '1000000114334946',
        purchase_date: '2014-07-1406: 53: 06Etc/GMT',
        purchase_date_ms: '1405320786698',
        purchase_date_pst: '2014-07-1323: 53: 06America/Los_Angeles',
        original_purchase_date: '2014-07-1313: 24: 59Etc/GMT',
        original_purchase_date_ms: '1405257899000',
        original_purchase_date_pst: '2014-07-1306: 24: 59America/Los_Angeles',
        expires_date: '2014-07-1313: 28: 34Etc/GMT',
        expires_date_ms: '1405258114000',
        expires_date_pst: '2014-07-1306: 28: 34America/Los_Angeles',
        web_order_line_item_id: '1000000028393887',
        is_trial_period: 'false'
    },
    {
        quantity: '1',
        product_id: 'com.purchase.test.debug.7.d.sub',
        transaction_id: '1000000116661121',
        original_transaction_id: '1000000114334946',
        purchase_date: '2014-07-1406: 53: 06Etc/GMT',
        purchase_date_ms: '1405320786698',
        purchase_date_pst: '2014-07-1323: 53: 06America/Los_Angeles',
        original_purchase_date: '2014-07-1313: 27: 59Etc/GMT',
        original_purchase_date_ms: '1405258079000',
        original_purchase_date_pst: '2014-07-1306: 27: 59America/Los_Angeles',
        expires_date: '2014-07-1313: 31: 34Etc/GMT',
        expires_date_ms: '1405258294000',
        expires_date_pst: '2014-07-1306: 31: 34America/Los_Angeles',
        web_order_line_item_id: '1000000028393889',
        is_trial_period: 'false'
    },
    {
        quantity: '1',
        product_id: 'com.purchase.test.debug.7.d.sub',
        transaction_id: '1000000116661354',
        original_transaction_id: '1000000114334946',
        purchase_date: '2014-07-1406: 53: 06Etc/GMT',
        purchase_date_ms: '1405320786698',
        purchase_date_pst: '2014-07-1323: 53: 06America/Los_Angeles',
        original_purchase_date: '2014-07-1313: 40: 16Etc/GMT',
        original_purchase_date_ms: '1405258816000',
        original_purchase_date_pst: '2014-07-1306: 40: 16America/Los_Angeles',
        expires_date: '2014-07-1313: 43: 15Etc/GMT',
        expires_date_ms: '1405258995000',
        expires_date_pst: '2014-07-1306: 43: 15America/Los_Angeles',
        web_order_line_item_id: '1000000028393892',
        is_trial_period: 'false'
    },
    {
        quantity: '1',
        product_id: 'com.purchase.test.debug.7.d.sub',
        transaction_id: '1000000116661448',
        original_transaction_id: '1000000114334946',
        purchase_date: '2014-07-1406: 53: 06Etc/GMT',
        purchase_date_ms: '1405320786698',
        purchase_date_pst: '2014-07-1323: 53: 06America/Los_Angeles',
        original_purchase_date: '2014-07-1313: 49: 51Etc/GMT',
        original_purchase_date_ms: '1405259391000',
        original_purchase_date_pst: '2014-07-1306: 49: 51America/Los_Angeles',
        expires_date: '2014-07-1313: 52: 50Etc/GMT',
        expires_date_ms: '1405259570000',
        expires_date_pst: '2014-07-1306: 52: 50America/Los_Angeles',
        web_order_line_item_id: '1000000028393900',
        is_trial_period: 'false'
    },
    {
        quantity: '1',
        product_id: 'com.purchase.test.debug.7.d.sub',
        transaction_id: '1000000116661526',
        original_transaction_id: '1000000114334946',
        purchase_date: '2014-07-1406: 53: 06Etc/GMT',
        purchase_date_ms: '1405320786698',
        purchase_date_pst: '2014-07-1323: 53: 06America/Los_Angeles',
        original_purchase_date: '2014-07-1313: 54: 18Etc/GMT',
        original_purchase_date_ms: '1405259658000',
        original_purchase_date_pst: '2014-07-1306: 54: 18America/Los_Angeles',
        expires_date: '2014-07-1313: 57: 17Etc/GMT',
        expires_date_ms: '1405259837000',
        expires_date_pst: '2014-07-1306: 57: 17America/Los_Angeles',
        web_order_line_item_id: '1000000028393905',
        is_trial_period: 'false'
    },
    {
        quantity: '1',
        product_id: 'com.purchase.test.debug.7.d.sub',
        transaction_id: '1000000116662149',
        original_transaction_id: '1000000114334946',
        purchase_date: '2014-07-1406: 53: 06Etc/GMT',
        purchase_date_ms: '1405320786698',
        purchase_date_pst: '2014-07-1323: 53: 06America/Los_Angeles',
        original_purchase_date: '2014-07-1314: 24: 36Etc/GMT',
        original_purchase_date_ms: '1405261476000',
        original_purchase_date_pst: '2014-07-1307: 24: 36America/Los_Angeles',
        expires_date: '2014-07-1314: 27: 36Etc/GMT',
        expires_date_ms: '1405261656000',
        expires_date_pst: '2014-07-1307: 27: 36America/Los_Angeles',
        web_order_line_item_id: '1000000028393909',
        is_trial_period: 'false'
    }
]}
```

Comment: do you have the receipt data text? Please post.

Comment: What do you mean by "active"? The one with the most recent date? BTW, there seems to be something wrong with the dates in the receipt you gave?

Comment: @ChrisPrince What I mean by active is, how do I verify that the users subscription has expired, renewed or was cancelled? I want to determine how to if the user still should have access to "premium content" or not.

Comment: also; shouldn't the field latest_receipt be valid json when decoded?

Comment: PLease share if you have got the solution for this.